# Download yearly median PROBA-V NDVI data using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, ndvi, proba-v

Using `Google Earth Engine` (GEE), I am trying to download yearly median NDVI data from PROBA-V. The output image has range 20-145.5.

[image: ndvi]

From [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/VITO_PROBAV_C1_S1_TOC_100M#description), it says:

> The reflectances provided in this dataset are presented as Digital
> Count Numbers (DN) and must be converted according to the guidelines
> in Section 4.6.1 of the user manual.

According to the [user manual](https://www.vito-eodata.be/PDF/image/PROBAV-Products_User_Manual.pdf), the equation to convert the DN to reflectance is:

> PV = (DN - OFFSET) / SCALE

where:

[image: table DN to reflectance]

From my code, it seems that I am doing wrong the equation because I am getting an error: `Line 25: median1.reproject is not a function`

Here is the [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f436c7811a82b1201c1b54a1921766c5):

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/nikostziokas/tehran_54009");

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('VITO/PROBAV/C1/S1_TOC_100M')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
                  .select('NDVI');
                  
var median1 = dataset.select('NDVI').reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).clip(table);

var median1 = (median1 - 20.0)/250.0;
                  
// Project the image to Mollweide.
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';

var proj_mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);
var image_mollweide = median1.reproject({
  crs: proj_mollweide,
  scale: 100
});

Export.image.toDrive({
image: image_mollweide,
description: 'ndvi',
scale: 100, //100 for Band10
maxPixels: 1000000000000,
region: table,
folder: 'Landsat-5'});
```

Comment: The script you link to and the pasted code doesn't match. There's an obvious error in the pasted code where you're using client-side operations (`-` and `/`) on the image. The linked code runs, except for `table`, which you didn't share. After picking some random area for `table`, `image_mollweide` renders on the map. An unrelated note - you take the effort to reproject your image, only to override that projection when exporting. You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: Sorry, because I tried many thinks I must have pasted the wrong code. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do client-side operations on server-side objects like an image. You can read up on it [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server). Something like this would do it:

```
var median1 = dataset.select('NDVI').reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).clip(table)
  .subtract(20).divide(250)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c9a40dab0a2bf698b5b7729937612c5f